# Which jobs have occupational hazards?

Tags: banished

It seems that, in addition to dying of old age, workers can die randomly when occupying certain jobs. So far I've witnessed:

- **Stonecutters** crushed by rocks
- **Foresters** killed by falling trees
- **Herdsman** trampled by livestock

What other jobs are potentially deadly for citizens in Banished?

Comment: It took me a little while to realise you weren't talking about real life…

Answer (score 16):

Complete List can be found [here](http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Death)

- Miners and Laborers getting crushed by a cave-in
- Stonecutters getting crushed by rocks in quarries
- Hunters getting trampled to death by boars
- Fishermen drowning
- Blacksmiths dying after being burned in the forge
- Gatherers eating poisonous berries
- Vendors getting stabbed to death in the market
- Builders falling off a ladder
- Physicians taking a bad medicine
- Teachers going crazy and being banished
- Brewers drinking a bad brew
- Traders committing suicide
- Foresters crushed by a falling tree
- Woodcutters being killed by an axe

On a sidenote

> Complications during childbirth

would not be work related but can also happen.

Comment: Wait, you can get banished from banished?!

Comment: @aslum your initial citizens are actually a group of insane teachers exiled from your last village.